# makeFirstResponder does not always fire

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstoolbar, nssearchfield

I have an `NSSearchField` inside a `NSToolbar` that I am attempting to set `makeFirstResponder` on but it is working intermittently. At times the `NSSearchField` will become the first responder without the call to `makeFirstResponder` and `makeFirstResponder` is returning `true` as if it were set successfully. Setting `NSWindow.initialFirstResponder` has also failed to work.

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    override func viewDidAppear() {
        super.viewDidAppear()
        view.window?.makeFirstResponder(view.window?.windowController?.searchField
    }
}
```

I have had consistent working results by delaying the code with a timer but this is a less than ideal solution.

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    override func viewDidAppear() {
        super.viewDidAppear()
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: false) { _ in
            self.view.window?.makeFirstResponder(self.windowController?.searchField)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Setting `initialFirstResponder` in the storyboard works for me. Is the searchfield defocused because the window is deactivated?

Comment: The window is not deactivated. It's being made key and front as I'd expect it's just intermittently not focusing the NSSearchField.

Comment: Is it possible to reproduce the issue in a small test project?

Comment: I've gotten to where a WKWebView is stealing the firstResponder from the searchField. I'm not sure why this is happening but this gets me to another step in debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a [blog](http://www.extelligentcocoa.org/the-strange-case-of-initialfirstresponder/) that led me to find the reason why this was happening. By default in macOS an NSWindow has an isRestorable Boolean value that will recall whatever the last `firstResponder` was regardless of what is set as an `initialFirstResponder` or what is set inside `viewDidAppear`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If `makeFirstResponder` is returning `true`, then the it likely was made the first responder for at least a short amount of time.

You can use the fact that `NSWindow.firstResponder` is KVO compliant in order to detect any changes to it with something like the following code in your `ViewController` class:

```
    override func viewDidAppear() {
        super.viewDidAppear()

        self.view.window?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "firstResponder", options: [.initial, .new], context: nil)
        self.view.window?.makeFirstResponder(self.windowController?.searchField)
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if keyPath == "firstResponder" {
            print("First responder of window: \(object) is \(change?[NSKeyValueChangeKey.newKey])")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I am using a WKWebView inside the window and I'm not sure the reason but this is sometimes stealing the firstResponder from the searchField.

Answer (score 0):

I found that calling webView.makeFirstResponder() didn't do anything.
But calling view.window?.makeFirstResponder(webView) did.

no idea why.
hours of frustration.